# How can I edit and delete a row?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a table:

```
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> ID </th>
            <th> Job</th>
            <th> Title</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

I also have a modal that creates a new row when the user clicks submit and it takes that data and creates a new row.  Next to each row, I want 2 icons, an edit and a delete icon.  I'm just curious, how can I set it up to where if the user selects "edit", it will only edit that one row, or if the user selects "delete" it will delete just that row.

This would be easier if I had ID's I feel like, but I can't create random ids when a user creates a new row.

How should I go about tackling this?

Here's what it looks like when a user creates a new row:

```
let id = document.getElementById('id').value;
let job = document.getElementById('job').value;
let title = document.getElementById('title').value;
$('#table').append('<tr><th class="icon"><button class="btn"><i class="mdi mdi-pencil" title="Edit"></i></button><button class="btn"><i class="mdi mdi-delete" title="Delete"></i></button></th><th>'+id+'</th><th>' + job + '</th><th>' + title + '</th></tr>')
```

Sorry if this is a bit messy.  I'm not to experienced and this was the only way I knew how to add the data the user inputs into a row.

Thank you!

Comment: You can deal with this by using something like document.getElementsByTagName("tr"). So, after that get the index. It works.

Comment: and why exactly you can't create a random id?

Comment: You can just use jquery to get the tr in your onclick handler. May be easier if you add a delete class to the button itself but something like this.

$('button.btn').on('click', function(){$(this).closest('tr').remove()});

Answer (score 2):

Just use jQuery to find the closest row and remove it. I did a delete class to the delete button to make it easier. Similar concept for editing a row, once you have a reference to the row you can drill down into the elements you want to edit.

```
$('#table').append('<tr><th class="icon"><button class="btn"><i class="mdi mdi-pencil" title="Edit"></i></button><button class="btn delete"><i class="mdi mdi-delete" title="Delete"></i></button></th><th>'+id+'</th><th>' + job + '</th><th>' + title + '</th></tr>');

$('button.delete').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.remove()` on the `<tr>` element to completely remove it from the table by ID.

```js
function deleteJob(id) {
    $("#job-" + id).remove();
}

deleteJob(1);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- JQuery -->
</head>

<body>
    <table id="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> ID </th>
            <th> Job</th>
            <th> Title</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr id="job-1">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>A Job</td>
            <td>A Job Title</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="job-2">
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Another Job</td>
            <td>Yet Another Title</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="job-3">
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Final Job</td>
            <td>Final Title</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The data-id links to the id of the current row so you can access the row using the value of the data-id attribute of the button clicked.

```
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
$('#table').append('<tr id="' + rand + '"><th class="icon"><button class="btn" data-id="' + rand + '"><i class="mdi mdi-pencil" title="Edit"></i></button><button class="btn" data-id="' + rand + '"><i class="mdi mdi-delete" title="Delete"></i></button></th><th>'+id+'</th><th>' + job + '</th><th>' + title + '</th></tr>')
```

NOTE: the rand variable must be recalculated every time the user inserts a row